# generating function for counting number of ways to distribute balls to 5 people

Tags: combinatorics

Question: find a generating function for the number of ways to distribute n identical juggling balls to five different jugglers if each juggler receives at most seven balls. 
And then compute how many ways 25 balls can be distributes with the generating function.

This what I think the generating function is:
(1 + Z^1 + Z^2 ..... + z^7)^5

And then for the numbers of ways 25 balls can be distributed in the manner as stated in the question would be: 14Cr10

Are my answers correct?

Comment: You have the correct GF, but for the second part you need to find the coefficient of z^25 when the GF is expanded.

Comment: Is that not 14 choose 10?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^{25]}}&\color{blue}{(1+z+z^2++z^7)^5}\\
> &=[z^{25}]\left(\frac{1-z^8}{1-z}\right)^5\tag{1}\\
> &=[z^{25}]\left(1-\binom{5}{1}z^8+\binom{5}{2}z^{16}-\binom{5}{3}z^{24}\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{-5}{j}(-z)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([z^{25}]-5[z^{17}]+10[z^9]-10[z]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{j+4}{4}z^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{29}{4}-5\binom{21}{4}+10\binom{13}{4}-10\binom{5}{4}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=926}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[final geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.
- In (2) we expand $(1-z^8)^5$  up  to  powers of  $z^{24}$, since higher powers do not contribute. We  also  apply  the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (3) we use the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.  We also apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we select the coefficients accordingly.